# First show and then hide an object on a PowerPoint slide

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint-2007, animation

I have a slide that has 2x content boxes and 1x image.

It's set up so that the first content box shows point by point on click, then the image, then the second content box (point by point on click).

When I'd like to do is hide the first content box when the image is shown. Is this possible, as it appears that you can only do one animation per object on each page? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, trying to figure this out now too. I have no use for it but got me wondering, and I can't seem to find a way either.

One simple (read - inelegant) solution would be to animate a solid box over the top of the first content box 0.0s after the image is shown. I presume then content box 2 would go in the same place?

Answer (score 18):

To apply additional animation effects to the same object, select it, click Add Animation and pick another animation effect.

After applying the first animation effect, if you try to add more animation effects any other way other than clicking Add Animation, you won’t apply an additional effect. Instead, you’ll replace the existing effect with a the one you’re adding.

[Source](https://support.office.com/article/Apply-multiple-animation-effects-to-one-object-9bb7b925-ab0f-47d4-bc11-85d939194bed)

Comment: This should be marked as the right answer.

Comment: A brief note to Mac users who might be as frustrated about this as I was 30 minutes ago: There is not even an "Add Animation" button, menu command, context menu command, etc. (at least not in PowerPoint 2021 for Mac), and it really looks like you simply can't have multiple animations for a single object. However, if you make sure no animations are selected (just as Pontus has described), then clicking on an animation effect in the ribbon bar will add it to the selected object instead of replacing an existing animation effect.